# How does JavaScript's in object feature work?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and something I cannot understand at the moment is this example below.  Using `in` to check if an item exist in the Object on the right side.

This code will merge user options into default options.

What is confusing to me is the `i` is not defined anywhere, so how does it know what `i` is?
If I print out `i` inside of the `for` block, it lists every `option` of my object.

I have read [MDN's article about the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) but it does not explain this handling of an undefined variable.

```
var i;
for(i in options) {
  if(i in this.options) {
    this.options[i] = options[i];
  } else {
    throw new Error("Notice doesn't support option: " + i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different kinds of "in":

- [For ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- [The in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

The first `in` in your code is not the `in` operator. It is a For ... in loop which iterates through the keys of an object assigning each key to the variable which in this case is `i`.

The second `in` in your code is the oner that you have already read the docs for. An operator which returns true or false.

Note: Unless you have `var i` earlier in that function scope, you are declaring a global variable `i` by leaving out the `var` keyword in your loop. You most likely want:

```
for(var i in options){
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I actually do have it set as var i; at the top of my app but based on the `in` documentation I couldn't figure out where the values for it were coming from.  The `For in` was the ticket, thanks

Comment: +1 because I didn't realize he was using a different `in` operator and so my answer missed the relevant point.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a result of the `for ... in` operator specifically.

Any time you try to assign to a variable which is not defined, it [creates a global variable of that name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Declaring_variables). Global variables are properties of the `window` object, so you can observe this behaviour as follows:

```
for (i in [0]) {
    alert(window.i); // displays "0"
}
```

```
i = 0
alert(window.i); // displays "0"
```

However this is considered an unfortunate and confusing  mis-feature in the language; most of the time you don't need or want a global variable. Relying on this behaviour is strongly discouraged, and it won't even work [if you enabled strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) by putting `'use strict'` as the first line of your script of function.

You should always use `var i` to declare a variable before or when you first assign to it.

```
for(var i in options) {
  if(i in this.options) {
    this.options[i] = options[i];
  } else {
    throw new Error("Notice doesn't support option: " + i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is confusing to me is the `i` is not defined anywhere, so how does
>   it know what `i` is?

well you can do something like this

```
for(var i in options) {
  if(i in this.options) {
    this.options[i] = options[i];
  } else {
    throw new Error("Notice doesn't support option: " + i);
  }
}
```

now its being defined.

to explain it more further

> ```
> for(<variable to hold the value on every loop> in <collection>)
> ```

The JavaScript `for/in statement` **loops through the properties** of an object